# Ruby For Each Loop Passing Result Into Method Argument

Tags: ruby, foreach

I am a novice programmer and have been teaching myself Ruby for the past couple of weeks. I am having a problem with a program (CSV importer / JSON exporter) that I hope someone can help with.

```
def convert_csv_to_json(csv_file_name)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file_name) do |row|
      JSON.pretty_generate(row)
    end
    test = FileExportManager.new
    test.export_json_to_computer(csv_file_in_json)
  end
```

I want the `export_json_to_computer` method to export the result of the foreach loop as a parameter. I haven't been able to achieve this. Can anyone offer any suggestions? Thanks.

***Edit - have included edited version FileExportManager class***

```
class FileExportManager

  def export_json_to_computer(file)
    write_to_file(file)
  end

  def assign_file_name
# this method names file and assigns .json extension
    File.new(file_name, 'w')
  end

  def write_to_file(file)
    File.open(file_name, 'w') do |row|
      row.puts file
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us what the `FileExportManager` class looks like.

Comment: Hi Tamer. I edited the original post to contain a condensed version of the FileExportManager class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on how you have your code currently structured, you want to read the csv file into memory and then convert it to json and pass the string to your `export_json_to_computer` file, as below:

```
def convert_csv_to_json(csv_file_name)
  rows = JSON.pretty_generate(CSV.read(csv_file_name).to_a)
  test = FileExportManager.new
  test.export_json_to_computer(rows)
end
```